# Get all the profiles a user has not voted on SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
profiles:
+--------+
id
name
surname

voted:
+--------+
id
profileid
targetid
```

I have a table with user profiles and another table where I keep track of who has voted on who. (`profileid` being the profile id of the voter and `targetid` the profile id of the person voted for)

I would like to:

Get all the profiles of people that a current user (say with id 1) has **not** voted on (also excluding himself).

I tried this:

```
SELECT profiles.name,profiles.surname,voted.targetid 
FROM profiles 
JOIN voted 
ON profiles.id = voted.profileid
WHERE profiles.id != 1 # exclude self
```

See a live [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80a6b/2) here, which doesn't work as I'm not sure how to form the JOIN.

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
SELECT 
  profiles.name,
  profiles.surname
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN voted 
  ON profiles.id = voted.targetid
  AND voted.profileid = 1 /* <- your param here */
  AND voted.profileid != voted.targetid 
    /* has not voted for him/herself */
WHERE voted.profileid is null
```

Here are the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80a6b/14

It works because of the `LEFT JOIN` in conjunction with the `WHERE` clause.

The JOIN looks for people that the profile has voted on (excluding self votes), and the WHERE selects the opposite of that (where the `LEFT JOIN` brings null values).

Note that I suppressed the `targetid` column from the output, as I think it does not make sense (we're looking for pairs where a vote does *not* exist).

Answer (score 1):

I will do this:

```
SELECT p.name
    ,p.surname
FROM profiles AS p
WHERE p.id NOT IN (
    SELECT targetId
    FROM voted
    WHERE profileId = 1
    )
    AND p.id <> 1
```

I assumed that both profileId and targetId are foreign key and connected to profiles.id

What this query do is FIRST to select ALL targetId from the table voted where the profileId is what I choose (in our case is 1), this mean that we are selecting the IDs of the people that my user voted on (because a vote is registered in the table)

Then I want to select all the people that IS NOT in this list. TADAH, I have all the people that haven't got a vote (yet) from my selected user.

And no JOIN

EDIT: I forgot to check that the user had not be selected in the query, solved by adding a p.id <> 1 (that mean p.id different from 1)